# About a programming language starts with <# #>

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, javascript

Is that a Javascript code??

The following code inside a php class file but after closing php tag start these lines and the [data] variable not defined in this class i want to trace the [data] variable, where could i find it .. in js files?? and how the data passed through this variable inside php class (not even in global namespace)

```
<# if ( data.tooltip ) { #>
   <a href="#" data-hint="{{ data.tooltip }}"></a>
<# } #>
```

Thanks,

Best

Comment: This does look like template of some kind, but without more details guessing is impossible. A lot of templating engines have similar syntax. Just work through the rest of the code and figure out what moving parts are being used.

Comment: Thanks pal, i found a lot of this tag [ <# ] inside the WordPress core in [wp-admin/themes.php] but i don't understand where's the [data] variable and what is it contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking at core source then what you see it use is [Underscore.js template](http://underscorejs.org/#template). WordPress has slightly modified the syntax of templates themselves, but it's the library it uses.

As far as I remember it was added when some parts of admin interface became more *rich* and interactive, starting with media management. Unfortunately at the time (and still since) this part of WordPress is grossly underdocumented. As far as I am aware there is simply *none* official documentation for it.

You could check out the post [Intro to Underscore.js templates in WordPress](http://themehybrid.com/weblog/intro-to-underscore-js-templates-in-wordpress) for some introduction to the concepts and mechanics.